# Building a html, css & javascript pages for wordpress without php?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, layout

So as the titles already states, is it possible to build a fully functioning wordpress page layout/theme using only frontend languages? And how will I incorporate it into wordpress without php?

Thanks!!!

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-a-simple-html-page

Comment: The manual should be your first port of call **not SO**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well no but you could certainly get away with using very little.
Just have

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

at the top of every page and

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

at the bottom

A page named header.php with

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

at the top and a page named footer.php with

```
<?php wp-footer();?>
```

at the bottom should get you going. From there just use html and javascript like normal.

HOWEVER this is leaving out 99% of the reasons to make a WordPress theme in the first place. It's a good place to start learning but if you want to make themes your gonna want to learn php.
This tutorial worked well for me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7olvEeBM2I&index=3&list=PLpcSpRrAaOaqMA4RdhSnnNcaqOVpX7qi5

Good luck!